# Import other news portals data to our website?

Tags: php, mysql, xml, rss

I want to import latest news from other news portal in to my php website.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read their "RSS Feed", and just display them on your site, It will be live updating too. 
Or you can just scrap the site via cURL, and store the contents in db or display them directly on your site.

But please do read the site's Privacy Policy. :)
Thanks